# Survey weighting

Tags: statistics, data-analysis

I took a survey of 142 people,

```
Answer  Quantity %Population Quantity likes apples  %Percent apples
Male    56  0.3943661972    31  0.5535714286
Female  85  0.5985915493    53  0.6235294118
Other   1   0.007042253521  1   1
```

I would like to be able to weight the quantity of those who like apples and are male by its "accuracy" based off the total population.

How could this be achieved? Am I thinking about this correctly?

Comment: What do you mean "accuracy"?  Presumably everybody who responded did so accurately.  What do you want to weight?  What would be more normal is to have some other questions and see if the male apple likers answer those differently from the rest of the population.

Comment: If there's 31 males who like apples, there 25 who do not. I know this less precisely than the rate at which women prefer apples because they have a larger sample population. I'm wondering how to standardize this value to account for the reduction in precision.